# Connecting to an Azure SQL Server Data Warehouse from R on a Mac - See random names instead of tables

Tags: r, sql-server, macos

I'm trying to connect to an Azure SQL Server (12.00.1900) from R on a Mac, using Microsoft's `unixodbc` SQL Server drivers (17).

I get a connection, but instead of seeing the 12 or so tables that live in the database, `dbListTables` returns 442 tables, all with nonsensical names, beginning with 'Csoe', 'Ote', and ending in 'xlshm_idad'. Instead of seeing the single schema that lives in the database, I see `cin_1mro__e`, `IFRAINSHM`, and `s`, none of which have any tables in them.

Note that when I use an ordinary SQL visualization app, that doesn't use the MS drivers, I'm able to see the tables and their content properly.

In addition, the `RSQLServer` package gets a working connection and sees the tables correctly, but isn't compatible with `dplyr` semantics.

Can anyone help or advise? I've looked for third party SQL Server `unixodbc` drivers for Mac, and I can't find any.

Comment: plz post the relevant contents of your odbc.ini file...
From a shell terminal, can you perform: $ `isql -v dsn user pwd` ? 
and can you view schema correctly?

Comment: also, plz post the R code you use to establish your odbc connection

Answer (score 0):

Until I see more info from OP, I'll leave as my answer the general recommendation to use R's `odbc` package. Assuming the correct drivers are installed, connection is configured correctly in odbc.ini, and assuming trusted_connection=yes is used in the same, then connecting from R is as simple as:

```
library(odbc)
dbConn <- dbConnect(odbc(), dsn = "myDSN")
```

if trusted connection is not on then you just need to pass uid and pwd arguments.

Also, it may be the case OP that you did not install freeTDS, so try (replace with equivalent for package manager you're using):

```
brew install freetds --with-unixodbc
```

This gives you the `libtdsodbc.so` driver. Make sure the DSN points to this.